# Enforce port number for ssh-copy-id

Tags: 14.04

**EDIT**

I solved this by using `ssh-copy-id "user@host -p 4444"`

---

For some reason my remote machine tries to connect to port 22 on my box, so I use commands such as `scp -v -oPORT=4444 nickeleres.tar.gz root@nickeleres.com:~` wherein I specify the port number of my nginx config.  Fine.

Im wondering how I can enforce `port 4444` for `ssh-copy-id username@remote_host` command in order to add another remote to my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ssh-copy-id -p 4444 username@remote_host
```

This will make `ssh-copy-id` to connect to port 4444 of "remote_host" for transferring and adding the public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the "remote_host".

Comment: `Bad port 'umask 077; test -d .ssh || mkdir .ssh ; cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys; test -x /sbin/restorecon && /sbin/restorecon .ssh .ssh/authorized_keys'`

Comment: @redress: `ssh-copy-id` sometimes have issues with ports. Try `ssh-copy-id "username@remote_host -p 4444"` or `ssh-copy-id -o port=4444 username@remote_host`

Comment: i had to use quotes, I think we figured out at the same time haha.  thank you very much